# The derivative estimates of this function

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, let

$$w(x)=\sqrt{\sin^2 x_1+\cdots+\sin^2 x_n}\,,$$

and

$$|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}\;.$$

Let

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{w(x)}-\frac{1}{|x|}.$$

Then how to prove that

$$|\partial^{\alpha} f(x)|\leq C_\alpha |x|^{1-|\alpha|},\;\;\mbox{as}\;\;|x|\rightarrow 0,$$

for all multi-index $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^n$, $C_\alpha$ is a constant depend on $\alpha$.

If $n=1$, then (consider $x>0$ is enough)
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}$$
and this case is easy. In higher dimensions, I want to expand $f(x)$ at $0$ but it is a little hard.

> **Comments:** We can reduce this question to estimate $$\partial^{\alpha}(|x|f(x))=\partial^{\alpha}\left(\frac{|x|}{w(x)}\right)$$
> for $|\alpha|\geq 1$.  We eliminate the radical and consider the derivative of
> $$g(x):=\frac{|x|^2}{w^2(x)}.$$
> Then it suffices to consider
> $$\partial^{\alpha}(w^2(x)g(x))=\partial^{\alpha}(|x|^2)$$
> and by an induction we can derive the desired conclusion.

Comment: By a tedious computation, I think I can prove it. See the above comments. Is there any better ideas?

Comment: $C_\alpha$ is a real constant or it depends on $\alpha$?

Comment: depend on $\alpha$